# Stop gitlab runner to not remove a directory

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a directory which is generated during a build and it should not be deleted in the next builds. I tried to keep the directory using cache in .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
cache:
  key: "$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME"
  untracked: true
  paths:
    - target_directory/
build-runner1:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./build-platform.sh target_directory
```

In the first build a cache.zip is generated but for the next builds the target_directory is deleted and the cache.zip is extracted which takes a very long time. Here is a log of the the second build:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.11.
  on Runner1
Using Shell executor...
Running on Runner1...
Fetching changes...
Removing target_directory/
HEAD is now at xxxxx Update .gitlab-ci.yml
From xxxx
Checking out xxx as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Checking cache for master...
Successfully extracted cache
```

Is there a way that gitlab runner not remove the directory in the first place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need is to use a **job artifacts**:

> Artifacts is a list of files and directories which are attached to a
> job after it completes successfully.

`.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
your job:
    before_script:
        - do something
    script:
         - do another thing
         - do something to generate your zip file (example: myFiles.zip)
  artifacts:
    paths:
         - myFiles.zip
```

After a job finishes, if you visit the job's specific page, you can see that there is a button for downloading the artifacts archive.

## Note

- If you need to pass artifacts between different jobs, you need to use **dependencies**.
- Gitlab has a good documentation about that if you really have this need http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#dependencies

Comment: Does not work for me. Neither with dependencies or needs. The runner has version 12.6

Answer (score 4):

For Gitlab Runner >= 11.10, you can use `GIT_CLEAN_FLAGS`

`.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
variables:
  GIT_CLEAN_FLAGS: -ffdx -e target_directory/
script:
  - ls -al target_directory/
```

According to the log you posted, it is `git clean` which remove your `target_directory`.

So you can tell `git clean` not to remove your `target_directory` by setting variable `GIT_CLEAN_FLAGS` as [documented by GitLab & git](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#git-clean-flags).